# Mixing text with react-components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I habe a component with outputs pure text mixed with react-components. something like:

```
<div>
  lorem ipsum <b>dolor</b>,{' '}
  some <a href="#">link</a> and{' '}
  again text.
  <i>great</i>.
</div>
```

When rendering this, react outputs me a warning

> Each child in an array or iterator should have a unique "key"

I was wondering how to solve this.

Comment: Are you sure there isn't something else going on? I'm not getting that warning here: https://jsfiddle.net/6y5sgss5/. Is your mixed content in a div or a different container that may be doing Array stuff behind the scenes?

Comment: I don't see any warning being rendered with the code you shared.  Are you very sure that this piece of code is displaying the warning ?

Comment: I'm actually really confused because even my reallife example applied to your fiddle will not reproduce the warning.
what strangely will solve it is adding keys to each JSX-element, like: `Do you really want to notify all users in <b key="b">{selectedCompany.name}</b> about the latest changes?`

Answer (score 0):

Remove extra curly brackets

```
<div>
  lorem ipsum <b>dolor</b>,some <a href="#">link</a> and again text <i>great</i>.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

From https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity

So, you can add keys by passing them to your Component like this:

```
<YourComponent key={index} />
```

But, be aware that item index should only be a last resort for a key.

> When you don’t have stable IDs for rendered items, you may use the item index as a key as a last resort: